# How can I update my bottom sheet variable state from another page inside the bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I have created a bottom sheet that can navigate between two pages within it. When I click on "List," it opens a list that I can select from, but the selection does not reflect on the first page of the bottom sheet. Additionally, the back button from the second page does not show the navigation between the pages, and I have to close and open the bottom sheet to see any changes. Can you help me with best practices for this case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best practice for that is using `provider` and use `ChangeNotifier` as extend when you create the class for that and then you should use `notifyListeners()` method in your function that do the changes. read about it and how to use it.

See [this link](https://brewyourtech.com/complete-guide-to-changenotifier-in-flutter/)
and [this link](https://medium.com/devtechie/providing-the-data-model-and-notifying-the-listening-widgets-in-flutter-29cc46b1d04d)

You'll get the idea how to handle it.